# jQuery divs slideDown on category selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slide, categories

I have hidden div tags in my html which i want to display them when a user select some category, but i have more hidden divs becuase its a big site. And i should display them when a user select certain category.

My problem here is that i'm new to jQuery and i really dont know if this is the right way but i know that i have problem doing like this way in this fiddle :

[`Here is a fiddle to check`](http://jsfiddle.net/v53uQ/)

There is no problem when i first select the first category but then when i select some other and back again to the first problem dont work properly. I dont understand where can be the problem.

Or should i use this all slideDown in one category on change function ?

If someone can help me here in this situations and give me a very proper way of using slideDown like in this situations.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the relevant code.!

Comment: The relevant code is too big. Like you see in the fiddle i have the same problem with my relevant code. I'm just wondering if i'm doing this slideDown on category change correctly.

Answer (score 1):

**i would do it this way**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#dropdown').on('change', function () {
         $('.common-class-for-all-hidden-divs').hide();
        var selection = $(this).val();

           $('#category_show_'+selection).show('slow');

    });
});
```

**one of the hidden divs example**

```
<div id="category_show_3" class="common-class-for-all-hidden-divs" >
        <select name="category_show_3">
            <option value="">category_show_3</option>
            <option value="1">category_show_3</option>
            <option value="2">category_show_3</option>
            <option value="3">category_show_3</option>
            <option value="4">category_show_3</option>
            <option value="5">category_show_3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

**css part --**

```
.common-class-for-all-hidden-divs{
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is very good example prince. But not so appropriate for my case. In some other cases i will be glad to use this example.

Comment: check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v53uQ/2/ .this is what i got as per my understanding of your problem

Comment: I think it could work. Let me try this one and i will write again. Thanks price, very good one

Comment: This works very well but i need to hide ex. radio 2 with category 4 is selected. Or to show only 1 radio when category 2 is selected. How can i accomplish this?

Comment: Or example if i'm on category 1 and click on the second radio box then the input box to be hidden. When i click on the first one again to show while i'm on the category 1

Comment: its simple you are getting drop down variables already just play with it with if else loop..

Comment: i cant get get it work. exampl if im on category 1 when and click on the second box the input is hidden and then if i go to category 2 and click second radio box then the input i hiding again. the funcion if selection is 1 is still remembered